# msg.sender is always 0x00000000

Tags: solidity, ethers.js

I coded a small smart contract with 1 functions, the problem I am facing is when I call that function from the explorer or my front-end, the msg.sender is always 0x00000...

I deployed this with the goerli testnet and I am also logged in with the same testnet account.

Try the openCall read function on this contract - https://thirdweb.com/goerli/0x2D8Fccd58DdDe7583d8ab28A5a0A40877f543d59/explorer

This is the contract:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.9;

contract Receipt {
    event Deployed(address indexed deployer);

    constructor() {
        emit Deployed(msg.sender);
    }

    // Open function see if current user is admin
    function openCall() public view returns (string memory, address) {
        return ("Called Open", msg.sender);
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you are calling a publicly available view function. This call to a contract is 'free' and therefore can be sent without sending a transaction to the contract address.

If the function required a transaction, sender would not be '0x0'.

Comment: Thank you! I did not know a call does not pass the address (or transaction). Makes sense

Answer (score 2):

As 'House Y' mentioned, view function doesn't send transaction and doesn't need any fee, so this kind of functions doesn't need any signer and when there is no signer, there is no address.
I hope it make sense.

Comment: Yup makes sense now. Thanks!